# Python - Como obter os nomes dos drivers C: D: F: I:

Tags: python, tkinter

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou desenvolvendo uma `GUI` em `Python 3.6` utilizando `TKinter`. Cheguei num impasse onde tenho que obter as letras do drivers instalados e os respectivos nomes do mesmo modo em que aparecem no `Windows Explorer`. Ver figura em anexo.

Com o código abaixo consigo obter as letras dos drivers, mas não os nomes.

```
drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
```

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: Algo como `win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\")` resolve?

Comment: Anderson, O "win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\")" só funciona para o drive C:. Não exibe os nomes dos outros drivers.

Comment: Você tentou substituir a letra do driver a fim de obter os dados dos outros, tal como `win32api.GetVolumeInformation("D:\\")`? Aliás, não use o campo de respostas para comentários, para tais, use o campo de comentários (logo abaixo da pergunta tem o link **comentar**).

Comment: ('Win7', 1087985650, 255, 65470719, 'NTFS')
('554', 4258, 255, 262382, 'NTFS')
('', -790939965, 255, 13041919, 'NTFS')

Comment: @rbarreto ficou alguma duvida? Uma pergunta você é o Renato né?

Comment: Olá Renato e @rbarreto! Se estas contas forem a mesma confirmem aqui para vos ajudarmos a juntá-las numa só. Até breve!

Comment: Para mesclar as contas [entre com contato conosco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) e faça uma solicitção

Answer (score 2):

Conforme o Anderson sugeriu, use `win32api.GetVolumeInformation`, basta iterar com o `for`, assim:

```
import win32api

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')

for drive in drives:
    try:
        print(win32api.GetVolumeInformation(drive.strip()))
    except:
        pass
```